# React Native / Android: Show high resolution image

Tags: android, image, react-native

I'm working on an app that shows the floor plan of a trade fair. This is a high resolution (3500x4600), but fairly low file size (400kb) PNG image. I have a little component that allows to pan / zoom it.

Now it all works just fine on iOS, but on Android I just cannot get it to work. If I just try to load it in the normal RN (0.56) Image component I get a blank screen. I'm testing on an HTC One M8, which is not exactly brand new, but also not super low end (2 GB Ram). Funnily enough, if I convert it to a 2,6 MB jpg with the same dimensions, it will show up, though the quality is so bad, you cannot read any of the labels.

There are some mostly older github issues on this (like [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10470) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13600)), but none of those solutions (`android:largeHeap="true"`) work for me.

I tried using `react-native-svg`, but it has the same problem (I guess it eventually gets rasterized?).

I also tried using `react-native-fast-image`, which uses Glide under the hood instead of Facebook's Fresco, but (you guessed it), it also doesn't work. If I just load the image, it will get downsampled (worse than the jpg). I tried to get Glide to stop doing that (using `override`), but then I get a blank screen again.

I found [this library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view), which I guess does exactly what I want, but I'd have to wrap it for RN use... which would be quite a bit of work.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have same problem. Are you find any fix for this?

Comment: Same issue did anyone solve this problem ?